# Expressão regular em python 3.6 para extração de frase inteitra

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-scraping

Preciso extrair somente as frases que contêm ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO B, por exemplo. Ou seja, preciso pegar somente o nome do curso, a cidade, o turno, o O SISU e o nome do grupo da seguinte string:

```
string = </li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=70>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO A</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=71>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO B</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=72>
```

A string é imensa, isso é só um pedaço.
Eu consegui fazer uma mas ela está retornando coisas picadas, e também, não está pegando letras com acento, como por exemplo o "ó" acentuado de HISTÓRIA.
A expressão que fiz foi essa

```
cursos = re.findall(([A-Z])\w+g)
```

Eu preciso que saia isso :

```
ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO A
```

Mas ela me retorna isso:

```
GEOGRAFIA - JUIZ DE FORA - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO( não está pegando qual grupo é)
```

e em HISTORIA por exemplo ela não pega o "Ó" acentuado.

Comment: Podes dizer também qual é o url a que estás a ir buscar o html sff? Seria mais facil para te ajudar e para ti

Comment: Neste caso não preciso das url's não, é somente das frases mesmo. As urls eu já extrai co outra expressão porque preciso delas em um local separado. É somente as frases mesmo.

Comment: Você PRECISA usar Python 2 para isso ? È muito melhor usar Python 3 - para começar, você não terá problemas com a acentuação.

Comment: (seu teclado não tem  ' " '?  estão faltando tanto no trecho de html quanto no código  Python  )

Answer (score 3):

Estava à espera que alguém que percebesse mesmo de regex respondesse mas vou dar-te uma [solução diferente](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (e em muitos casos [melhor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391/python-regular-expression-for-html-parsing-beautifulsoup), [melhor](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-regex-vs-Beautiful-Soup-in-web-scraping)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

string = '</li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=70>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO A</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=71>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO B</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=46A&id_grupo=72>'

soup = bs(string, 'html.parser')
aEles = soup.findAll('a')
texts = '\n'.join(i.text for i in aEles if i.text != '')
print(texts)
```

Isto vai imprimir:

> ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO A
> ADMINISTRAÇÃO
>   - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO B

Comment: A expressão regular pra isso não  é dificil - mas a resposta está correta:  é errado em alguns níveis depender de expressões regulares para extrair conteudo de marcaões HTML.   O correto é usar uma ferramenta que faça o parse do HTML e extraia o conteúdo "sabendo" que é o conteúdo como o beautfulsoup

Comment: @jsbueno concordo, obgado. Talvez faça com regex assim que chegar a casa

Comment: Com regex não precisa - já fiz abaixo.  :-)  O correto é com beautfulsoup mesmo.

Comment: @jsbueno ha lol, dsculpa não tinha reparado. Então o AP já tem ambas as soluçoes

Answer (score 2):

(1) Expressões regulares não são a ferramenta mais indicada para se extrair conteúdo de HTML - o melhor é usar um parser de HTML que faça isso -como o beautifulsoup listado na resposta do Miguel, ou o próprio módulo "HTMLParser" da biblioteca padrão do Python.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html
(Em Python 2 o módulo é `HTMLParser` em vez de `html.parser` - mas, insisto, você não deveria estar usando Python 2 - vai te deixar 10 anos atrás em funcionalides e facilididades, incluindo tratamento de caracteres acentuados)

(2)  Dito tudo isso, o problema com sua expressão regular é que você está com o foco errado - em vez de buscar as frases em si, que podem ter muitas variações, é bem mais fácil procurar o que está *em volta*  da frase, que é fixo (os tags `<a>` e `</a>` . )  Se houverem mais links além dos de interesse, você pode começar a complicar a sua expressão regular para pegar só o conteúdo dos  `<a>` que estiverem dentro de `<li>`, por exemplo (e aí você vai entender por que a recomendação NÃO É usar expressões regulares para isso)  - ou, depois de extrair todo o conteúdo das tags `<a>`, usar um filtro normal de Python com "for" e "if" para deixar só o que te interessa.  (pode ser mais legível e mais fácil que uma regexp complexa).

Com tudo isso dito, a expressão regular para recuperar tudo que está dentro das tags `<a>`, que você pode usar com o método `findall` é:

```
re.findall (r"<a.*?>(.*?)</a", string)
```

A saída que obtenho para o trecho de HTML que vocẽ colou é:

```
['ADMINISTRA\xc3\x87\xc3\x83O - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO A',
 'ADMINISTRA\xc3\x87\xc3\x83O - JUIZ DE FORA - NOTURNO - SISU - GRUPO B']
```

(Em Python 2.7 - em Python3, a acentuação do trecho dado já sai correta na representação)

Answer (score -1):

Usando regex para HTML formatado dessa maneira, você pode fazer assim:

```
regex = r'(?<=<a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-20\d{2}-\da-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-\d)(?:[\s\S]*?>)([-\x41-\x5A\xC0-\xDC\s]*?)(?:</a>)'
cursos = re.findall(regex, string)
```

Comment: Você gerou uma expressão regular automática, e postou seu conteudo sem prestar atenção no que ele faz: no caso a expressão regular pega exatamentne os carcatéres que estão na frase de exemplo da pergunta, mas vai falhar se a frase contiver letras diferentes . Esta resposta está incorreta.